# Spring Boot Cron using @Scheduled annotation does not pick up the expression from property file

Tags: spring-boot, cron, scheduler

I am trying to read cron expression from the property file for @Scheduled annotation

My application.properties looks like:

APPLICATION_CRONFORPURGESIM: 0 0 12 * * ?

When I change my cron expression to some other time for example 0 40 06 * * ? it just works fine, don't know how?

I am using the Kubernates based implementation where multiple pods are running for a single microservice.

I making the cron expressions using
https://www.javainuse.com/cron
http://www.cronmaker.com/?9

Comment: Are you unable to input the value of application.properties into @Scheduled?
Or does it mean that scheduling does not work properly when written as (cron = 0 0 12 * * ?)?.?

Comment: My Scheduler is using the cron expression as:
@Scheduled(cron = "${application.cronForPurgeSim}")
When I am configuring cron expression, for example: 0 0 12 * * ?. It is not picked at the mentioned time but when I change it to some other time it works but it is no surety with same cron expression it will work again. That's the issue I am facing.